# Intersection point (coordinates) of two paths given start points (coordinates) and bearings (degrees) in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, point, intersection, bearing

I'm dealing with geographic coordinates and geographic bearings (true north) and I want to get the intersection point of two points with different coordinates based on their azimuths (True north bearings), see below a print screen.

[image: Point 1 and Point 2 and the intersection point, Point 3]

While searching for a solution on the internet I came across this method with the formulas given, I tried to implement this on Python and after testing my code it does not give the correct result.

For those who are interseted in where I found that solution here is the link : https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

**Below is a print screen for the formulas used :**

[image: Method and formulas found online]

**My Python implementation :**

```
from cmath import pi
from math import radians, cos, sin, sqrt, degrees, asin, atan2, acos


# GPS Coordinates and bearing of point 1 and point 2
# Point 2
x1 = 3.252780556
y1 = 36.793608333
b1 = 0

# Point 1
x2 = 3.238638889
y2 = 36.798261111
b2 = 100

# Convert to radian
lon1 = radians(float(x1))
lat1 = radians(float(y1))
b1 = radians(float(b1))

lon2 = radians(float(x2))
lat2 = radians(float(y2))
b2 = radians(float(b2))

dlon = lon2 - lon1 # Distance between longitude points
dlat = lat2 - lat1 # Distance between latitude points

# Great-circle distance between point 1 and point 2
haversine = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2

# angular distance between point 1 and point 2
ang_dist_1_2 = 2 * asin(sqrt(haversine))

# Initial and final bearings between point 1 and point 2
initial_bearing = acos((sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(ang_dist_1_2)) / (sin(ang_dist_1_2) * cos(lat1)))
final_bearing = acos((sin(lat1) - sin(lat2) * cos(ang_dist_1_2)) / (sin(ang_dist_1_2) * cos(lat2)))

# Adjust the bearings on the trigonometric circle
if sin(x2 - x1) > 0:
    bearing_1_2 = initial_bearing
    bearing_2_1 = (2 * pi) - final_bearing

else:
    bearing_1_2 = (2 * pi) - initial_bearing
    bearing_2_1 = final_bearing


# Angles between different points
ang_1 = b1 - bearing_1_2    # angle p2<--p1-->p3
ang_2 = bearing_2_1 - b2    # angle p1<--p2-->p3
ang_3 = acos(-cos(ang_1) * cos(ang_2) + sin(ang_1) * sin(ang_2) * cos(ang_dist_1_2))    # angle p1<--p3-->p2

# angular distance between point 1 and intersection point (point 3)
ang_dist_1_3 = atan2(sin(ang_dist_1_2) * sin(ang_1) * sin(ang_2), cos(ang_2) + cos(ang_1) * cos(ang_3))

# Latitude of point 3
lat3 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(ang_dist_1_3) + cos(lat1) * sin(ang_dist_1_3) * cos(b1))

# Longitude of point 3
delta_long_1_3 = atan2(sin(b1) * sin(ang_dist_1_3) * cos(lat1), cos(ang_dist_1_3) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat3))
lon3 = lon1 + delta_long_1_3

# Print results
print("Lat3 : ", lat3)
print("Lon3 : ", lon3)
```

**The results obtained :**

[image: Results obtained with my Python implementation]

I don't know where my code is wrong, I will be glad if anyone can help with another method, or some library that can do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've not converted the radians to degrees. If I use the numbers in the screenshot from the converter tool:

```
# Point 2
x1 = 3.144767
y1 = 36.5934
b1 = 300

# Point 1
x2 = 3.13891666
y2 = 36.5923888
b2 = 60
```

and convert to degrees:

```
# Print results
print("Lat3 : ", degrees(lat3))
print("Lon3 : ", degrees(lon3))
```

your code gives me:

```
Lat3 :  36.594250296767775
Lon3 :  3.1429326206482537
```

The degrees-minutes-seconds given as answers in the screengrab can be converted to decimal degrees and agree well:

```
>>> 36 + (35/60)+(39/(60*60))
36.594166666666666
>>> 36 + (8/60)+(35/(60*60))
36.143055555555556
```

I'd expect some difference due to tolerances in numeric libraries, and that I can't see the exact decimal in the input boxes!

Comment: You're right ! it works well now ! thanks for helping, I've another question that popped when doing some tests right now to see if it works with all possibilities, what if the azimuths are parallels or in opposite directions where a cross point will not possible ?

Comment: Try it and see! Usually this sort of pathological case results in a division by zero, or a "Not a number" result, but the "Note" section in your screenshot might relate to some conditions you can test in your code to trigger a warning before bad things happen.

Comment: Hi, I've implemented the conditions and it does work for "most" of the cases, I've posted below my complet code with examples of some issues, if you can check it I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Spacedman I resolved the initial problem, you can find below my implementation in Python.

```
def geo_intersec_point(x1, y1, brng1, x2, y2, brng2):

"""
    This function calculate the intersection point if exists of two points\r\n
        given their coordinates (latitude and longitude in DD format) and bearings in degrees.\r\n
    x1      (float)     : Longitude of the first point (DD format).\r\n
    y1      (float)     : Latitude of the first point (DD format).\r\n
    brng1   (float)     : Bearing of the first point (degrees format).\r\n
    x1      (float)     : Longitude of the second point (DD format).\r\n
    y1      (float)     : Latitude of the second point (DD format).\r\n
    brng1   (float)     : Bearing of the second point (degrees format).\r\n
    return :\r\n
    error   (Bool)      : True if an error is detected.\r\n
    result  (dict, str) :  if error is True, return error message.
                           if error is False, return coordinates of intersection\r
                           point in a dict struct (DD format).\r\n
"""

# Check for errors
# Check data type
check_type((float, int), x1 = x1, y1 = y1, brng1 = brng1)
check_type((float, int), x2 = x2, y2 = y2, brng2 = brng2)

# Convert to radians (sin, cos and tan works with radians)
lon1 = radians(float(x1))
lat1 = radians(float(y1))
brng1 = radians(float(brng1))

lon2 = radians(float(x2))
lat2 = radians(float(y2))
brng2 = radians(float(brng2))

# Calculate the angular distance between point 1 and point 2
dlon = lon2 - lon1 # Distance between longitude points
dlat = lat2 - lat1 # Distance between latitude points

# Great-circle distance between point 1 and point 2
haversine = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2

# angular distance between point 1 and point 2
ang_dist_1_2 = 2 * asin(sqrt(haversine))

# Calculate the initial and final bearings between point 1 and point 2
initial_bearing = acos((sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(ang_dist_1_2)) / (sin(ang_dist_1_2) * cos(lat1)))
final_bearing = acos((sin(lat1) - sin(lat2) * cos(ang_dist_1_2)) / (sin(ang_dist_1_2) * cos(lat2)))

# Adjust initial and final bearings
if sin(x2 - x1) > 0:
    bearing_1_2 = initial_bearing
    bearing_2_1 = (2 * pi) - final_bearing

else:
    bearing_1_2 = (2 * pi) - initial_bearing
    bearing_2_1 = final_bearing


# Angles between different points
ang_1 = brng1 - bearing_1_2    # angle p2<--p1-->p3
ang_2 = bearing_2_1 - brng2    # angle p1<--p2-->p3

# Check for ambiguous or inifite intersection
# infinite intersections   
if sin(ang_1) == 0 and sin(ang_2) == 0:
    return  True, "infinite intersections"

# ambiguous intersection (antipodal/360°)
if sin(ang_1) * sin(ang_2) < 0:
    return  True, "ambiguous intersections"

# if no errors, calculte intersection point angle, latitude and longitude
ang_3 = acos(-cos(ang_1) * cos(ang_2) + sin(ang_1) * sin(ang_2) * cos(ang_dist_1_2))    # angle p1<--p3-->p2

# angular distance between point 1 and intersection point (point 3)
ang_dist_1_3 = atan2(sin(ang_dist_1_2) * sin(ang_1) * sin(ang_2), cos(ang_2) + cos(ang_1) * cos(ang_3))

# Latitude of point 3
lat3 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(ang_dist_1_3) + cos(lat1) * sin(ang_dist_1_3) * cos(brng1))

# Longitude of point 3
delta_long_1_3 = atan2(sin(brng1) * sin(ang_dist_1_3) * cos(lat1), cos(ang_dist_1_3) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat3))
lon3 = lon1 + delta_long_1_3

# Convert to degrees
lon3 = degrees(lon3)
lat3 = degrees(lat3)

# Return error flag as False and intersection points longitude and latitude
return False, {"x3" : lon3, "y3" : lat3}
```

The code seems to work fine, as I checked some scenarios, but I've found some issues even with the original tool (https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Below some examples of known issues in case anyone has an idea on how to fix them.

With :

- Point 1 : Longitude = 3.252780556 and Latitude = 36.793608333
- Point 2 : Longitude = 3.238638889 and Latitude = 36.798261111

**Parallel bearings**

With point 1 and point 2 having the same bearing (parallel) there should be no cross point, but the online tool and my code do give a result (wich is a wrong one).

- Point 1 : bearing = 0
- Point 2 : bearing = 0

[image: Both bearings equal 0, using the online tool]
[image: Both bearings equal 0, using my Python code]

- Point 1 : bearing = 100
- Point 2 : bearing = 100

[image: Both bearings equal 100, using the online tool]
[image: Both bearings equal 100, using my Python code]

**Not in the same direction bearings**

This one is a little tricky, I was testing some opposite bearings and I found that it does work for most of the bearings but for some values it doesn't.

Using the same points and with **point 1** having a **bearing = 0°** an intersection point should exists only if

> **0° < bearing of point 2 <= B**

As illustrated below, with **B** equal to the bearing from Point 2 to Point 1 thus **B = 112°**.

[image: Point 1 and Point 2]

Testing my code with :

> **0° <= bearing of point 2 <= 120°**

[image: Results for 0° <= bearing of point 2 <= 120°]

Seems to work fine except for the value 0° as said earlier.

> **130° <= bearing of point 2 <= 360°**

Works fine with bearing between 130° and 290°, but starting from the value 300° it starts giving false results.

[image: Results for 130° <= bearing of point 2 <= 360°]

**The same apply with the online tool and I suppose with the JavaScript code attached (link below) beign not familiar with it I didn't test it.**

[JavaScript implementation](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: Equal bearings seem to start off "parallel" but we are actually making great circles here. Two bearings of 0 will meet the north pole (and again at the south pole) which is what you see here.

Comment: Does the same apply for the angles starting from 300° to 350° with the angle 0° ? is it bold to assume that the for the above algorithm and except the two conditions for infinite and ambiguous intersection, it will always return the north pole point if no near intersection point is found ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a python implementation of this https://github.com/mrJean1/PyGeodesy.

```
from pygeodesy import sphericalNvector

# Point 2
x1 = 3.144767
y1 = 36.5934
b1 = 300

# Point 1
x2 = 3.13891666
y2 = 36.5923888
b2 = 60

s = sphericalNvector.LatLon(x1,y1)
e = sphericalNvector.LatLon(x2,y2)
s.intersection(b1, e, b2)`
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is this:

```py
import pygeodesy

lon1 = 3.252780556
lat1 = 36.793608333
az1 = 0

lon2 = 3.238638889
lat2 = 36.798261111
az2 = 100

#https://mrjean1.github.io/PyGeodesy/docs/pygeodesy.formy-module.html#intersection2
intersection = pygeodesy.formy.intersection2(lat1, lon1, az1, lat2, lon2, az2,
                                             datum=pygeodesy.Datums.WGS84)
```

But this function calls one out of five different methods, depending on various conditions.

To get best results, you need to be more specific and use geographiclib:

```
import pygeodesy
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic


s12 = 100_000

lon1 = 3.252780556
lat1 = 36.793608333
az1 = 0

lon2 = 3.238638889
lat2 = 36.798261111
az2 = 100

# dot+azimuth to geodesic "line"
geod_dict1 = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lat1, lon1, az1, s12, outmask=GeodesicCapability.ALL)
geod_dict2 = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lat2, lon2, az2, s12, outmask=GeodesicCapability.ALL)


# necessary type conversion
start1 = pygeodesy.ellipsoidalKarney.LatLon(geod_dict1['lat1'], geod_dict1['lon1'])
end1 = pygeodesy.ellipsoidalKarney.LatLon(geod_dict1['lat2'], geod_dict1['lon2'])
start2 = pygeodesy.ellipsoidalKarney.LatLon(geod_dict2['lat1'], geod_dict2['lon1'])
end2 = pygeodesy.ellipsoidalKarney.LatLon(geod_dict2['lat2'], geod_dict2['lon2'])

intersection = pygeodesy.ellipsoidalKarney.intersection3(start1, end1, start2, end2)
```